# ideavim - open a file with command mode?

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

I'm used to quickly opening a file in vim with :e  . Quick and simple, especially with tab filename completion.

However :e doesn't seem to be wired up to open files for ideavim. Typing :e  has no response.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:e` or `:edit` or `:action OpenFile` to open IntelliJ's 'Open File' dialog and then browse to the target file but there is no auto completion available for file paths/names.

There's an open issue against IDEA VIM for this:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-268

Answer (score 4):

Double tapping shift (at least in intellij's GoLand) allows super fast searching for files in your project and opening them in a new tab.  Not exactly the same as what you (and I) are looking for, but handy and fast.

Answer (score 3):

`nnoremap <leader>ff :action GotoFile<CR>` works quite well for me.

Answer (score 2):

`:sp` (alias for :split, splits editor screen horizontally) and `:vsp` (split vertically) also work in the way glytching described.

It's nutz that autocomplete for filename/paths isn't a feature.

I guess one sort of cool (probably unintended) feature is that you can `:e`, `:sp`, whatever just the filename of any file in your entire project. no need for path specifying (ie `:sp ../../dir1/filename` is unnecessary, just `:sp filename` works), so that's a possible workaround for the missing autocomplete.

Comment: you can bind them to the 'default' vim behaviour by adding the following 2 lines to your ~/.ideavimrc -> 

nnoremap <C-w>n :sp<CR>
nnoremap <C-w>v :vsp<CR>